# I am trying to add a hyperlink in my code but it doesn't seen to work

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to add a hyperlink for the link in the following line:

```py
embed.add_field(name='Invite Talent Builder to your own server:', value='https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=859135646061166613&permissions=68608&scope=bot', inline=False)
```

This is the rest of the code:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()

from discord.utils import find

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f'.help | On {len(client.guilds)} servers'))

  if message.content.lower().startswith('.help'):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='To use Talent Builder bot you need to type the name of the commander with a period at the beggining. Example: .richard | To view equipment guide for commanders type .equipment or .eq for short (Please DO NOT use special characters) (Case does not matter)')
    embed.set_author(name='Talent Builder', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/821829884967649291/860267265404305473/TB7.2t.png')
    embed.add_field(name='Invite Talent Builder to your own server:', value='https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=859135646061166613&permissions=68608&scope=bot', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Join our discord support server:', value='https://discord.gg/tyDuddtMWe', inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a hyperlink in field value or descripation use the following format which is actually MarkDown

```
[Title](URL)
```

So the field will be

```
embed.add_field(name='Join our discord support server:', value='[Click Here](https://discord.gg/tyDuddtMWe)', inline=False)
```